# Why was it called the Kalinda Khaki Club?

Tags: glitch

In S2E5 of *Glitch*, "The Walking Wounded", we see how Charlie played a large part in founding the Kalinda Khaki Club, a veterans club.

But why was it called the *Kalinda* Khaki Club?

Kalinda was someone from Paddy's past, not important to anyone else. How did Charlie, or possibly some other person picking the name, know about her?

Answer (score 2):

If you recall, Paddy said that he changed the name of the Fitzgerald estate to Kalinda, in honor of his wife.  You may also recall the scene where Charlie was receiving electro-shock therapy; that was inside Kalinda house, because as they said, it was taken over by the government for a short time to be utilized as a certain type of hospital called a "Repatriation Center." The subtext is that Charlie was receiving 'therapy' for his PTSD and homosexuality.

All of this is supported by Charlie's talks with that bar owner who knows all of Charlie's history. The Kalinda house was later given back to the Fitzgeralds when the government was done with it, and presumably that's when the name changed back from Kalinda to Fitzgerald estate (or whatever it's called). When Paddy was speaking with Adeline, she said "how did you know this house was called Kalinda? No one knows that outside of the family."

Comment: I formatted a bit to make it easier to read. If you think I did so in the wrong places, feel free to rollback and edit it yourself.